# Ordenar de forma descendente

Tags: java, array

Ayuda, en la clase ordenar necesito que se ordene de forma descendente y cuando inicio el código sale de forma ascendente.

Todo lo demás del código esta bien solo necesito que sea descendente

Y otro problema que tengo es de como poner el vector así:

> 1 2 3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me sale así:

> 1

> 2

> 3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en un 3x3

Necesito poner el vector 3x3 que quede mas estético

```
  public static void ordenar(int m[][]){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
          for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++){
            if (m[i][j] < m[x][y]){
              int t = m[i][j];
          m[i][j] = m[x][y];
          m[x][y] = t;
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

```
public static void imprimir(int m[][]){
    System.out.println("Los datos cargados son \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        System.out.println(" " + m[i][j]);
   }
      System.out.println("\n");
  }
 }
```

Comment: Solo cambia el signo `< ` por `>`  en el `if (m[i][j] < m[x][y])`  y problema resuelto.

Comment: cambia el `println` por `print` en `System.out.println(" " + m[i][j]);` para que visualices el arreglo bidimensional de la forma que indicas

Answer (score 0):

El mètodo para ordenar es correcto, el problema se encuentra cuando tratas de imprimir, genera muchos saltos de linea innecesarios.

Para solucionar el problema, puedes almacenar la iteraciòn de cada 3 elementos en una variable, por ejemplo en la variable `line` y al terminar el `for` imprimir usando `print()` para que no genere otro salto de linea extra:

```
 public static void imprimir(int m[][]){
    System.out.println("Los datos cargados son \n");
        String line = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
          for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            //System.out.println(" " + m[i][j]);
            line += m[i][j]; //almacena informaciòn
          }
           System.out.print(line + "\n");
           line = ""; //Limpia variable
        }
 }
```

de esta forma podras tener una salida como lo deseas, ejemplo:

```
int[][] m = { {7,9,8}, {3, 2, 1}, {6,5,4} };   
ordenar(m);
imprimir(m);
```

salida:

```
123
456
789
```